# Flask login page keeps loading and does not take to a new /main page where it is supposed to go?

Tags: python, apache, flask, wsgi

So, I have this flask application and I have used flask_login and flask forms to set up an authentication for my webpage. When I run it on a local development server, it works completely fine and upon putting right username and password, I am able to go to the main page which resides on /main route.

Now, I had to transfer this flask application to an ubuntu server and I worked around on getting apache2 to serve this flask application through wsgi. The problem is, authentication has stopped working all of a sudden now.

When I prompt username and password and click login the page keeps loading and never takes me to the main page with route /main. I have tried some options like setting WSGIPassAuthorization on in my apache conf. file but it has not really work.

I also have a register page that takes username and password and registers them. When I prompt a new username and password, same thing happens and that same page keeps loading on the tab.

My flask authentication code is down below:

```
from cgitb import reset
import tempfile
from numpy import column_stack
from ast import Str
import requests
#from requests import request
from flask import request
import ssl
import json
import ast
from flask import Flask, jsonify, redirect, render_template, request
import pandas as pd
import os
import js2py
import sys
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template
from os import path
import paramiko
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import UserMixin, login_user, LoginManager, 
login_required, logout_user, current_user 
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired, Length, ValidationError
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask import url_for
from flask import flash, session
from functools import wraps

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['TESTING'] = True

  

#For hashing password 
bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///database.db'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'thisisasecretkey'

login_manager= LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
   return User.query.get(int(user_id))


class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
username = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, unique=True)
password = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False)


class RegisterForm(FlaskForm):
   username = StringField(validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=4, 
                  max=20)], render_kw={"placeholder": "Username"})
   password = PasswordField(validators=[InputRequired(), 
          length(min=4, max=20)], render_kw={"placeholder": "Password"})
   submit = SubmitField("Register")

   def validate_username(self, username):
       existing_user_name = User.query.filter_by(
           username=username.data).first()


       if existing_user_name:
           raise ValidationError(
            "That username already exists. Please choose a different 
             one."
             )

 class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
       username = StringField(validators=[InputRequired(), 
       length(min=4, max=20)], render_kw={"placeholder": "Username"})
       password = PasswordField(validators=[InputRequired(), 
       length(min=4, max=20)], render_kw={"placeholder": "Password"})
       submit = SubmitField("Login")


 @app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

 def login():
     form = LoginForm()
     if form.validate_on_submit():
            user = 
  User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
   # flask.session["user"] = user
    if user:
        if bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, 
         form.password.data):
               login_user(user)
               return redirect(url_for('main_page'))

    return render_template('login.html', form=form)

  @app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
  def register():
        form = RegisterForm()
        if form.validate_on_submit():
        hashed_password = 
        bcrypt.generate_password_hash(form.password.data)
        new_user = User(username=form.username.data, 
        password=hashed_password)
        db.session.add(new_user)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('login'))

   return render_template('register.html', form=form)


 @app.route('/logout', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
 def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect('/')

@app.route('/main', methods=['GET', 'POST']
@login_required
def main_page(): 
    return render_template('index.html)
```

And I also have login.html and register.html templates that basically creates the form and takes username and password.

My apache2 conf file is below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName flaskapp.com
   ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
   WSGIPassAuthorization on
   WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/main.wsgi
   <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/>
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
   </Directory>
   WSGIScriptAlias /main /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/main.wsgi
   <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/>
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
   </Directory>
   Alias /static  /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static
   <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/>
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
   </Directory>
   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   Loglevel warn
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
 </VirtualHost>
```

My main.wsgi is down below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/FlaskApp/")
from FlaskApp import app as application
application.secret_key = 'thisismysecretkey'
```

My login.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Log in Page</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/login.css">
   {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
   {% if messages %}
       <ul class="flashes">
          {% for message in messages %}
             <li>{{message}}</li>
       </ul>
          {% endfor %}
   {% endif %}
   {% endwith %}
</head>
<body>
   <div class="sign-up-form">
       <img src="static/icon.jpg">
       <h1> Welcome to checkout app!</h1>
  
         <form method="POST" action="">
             {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
             {{ form.username(class_="input-box")}}
             {{ form.password(class_="input-box") }}
             {{ form.submit(class_="submit-button") }}


         </form>
         <hr>
         <p class="or">OR</p>
         <a href="{{ url_for('register')}}"><button type="button" class="sign-btn">Register yourself</button></a>
        
     
    <p>@test</p>
  </div>

</body>
```

So, I believe all the routes are defined fine, when I run apache2 I can see my login page since that is the / route. When I prompt username and password and click login, the login page keeps loading but never takes me to the main page. Same thing with register page. When I go to register url and put new username and password to register, then register page keeps loading but never take me back to login page.
Not sure if this is a database problem or routing problem.

Again, this works fine on a local development server with visual studio. Its giving me problem with this linux server only

Has anyone faced this problem before!

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Could you share the error you are getting? It may be an issue with the app not being able to connect to the database when on the server, but it is hard to tell what is happening with the limited detail you have given.

Comment: There are no erros on the log and that is the reason I am having hard time to reach to a conclusion. I am running a flask application on apache2 through wsgi and my flask app has a login page. When users provide login info they are supposed to be redirected to the main page. Right now when they provide the login info the login page keeps looping and I am never redirected to the main page. This works fine on the local development server through visual studio. But in my linux server through apache and wsgi, I am having this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, apparently I found the solution. The problem was with the import numpy in my python file. I had not really used the numpy so I removed it and the warnings for numpy went away and authentication started working again. The warnings I got from deprecated numpy probably caused some timeout issues (couldnot redirect to the main url because of timeout). So, removing or updating the numpy to latest version was the fix! Thanks!